# Basic navigation with PHP not working

Tags: php, html, css, post, classname

I have the following PHP page:

index.php

```
   if( isset($_POST['location']) ) {
            $location = $_POST['location'];

   } else {
        $location = 'home';
    }

require 'header.php';

switch ($location) {
    case "home": require 'home.php'; break;
    case "about": require 'about.php'; break;
    case "products": require 'products.php'; break;
    case "budget": require 'budget.php'; break;
    case "contact": require 'contact.php'; break;
    case "help": require 'help.php'; break;
    default: require 'home.php';
}

require 'footer.php';

?>
```

Inside the HEADER I have:

header.php

```
<body class="<?php echo $location; ?>">

<div id="navmenu">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a id="page_item_1" href="?location=home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a id="page_item_2" href="?location=about">About</a></li>
        <li><a id="page_item_3" href="?location=products">Products</a></li>
        <li><a id="page_item_4" href="?location=budget">Budget</a></li>
        <li><a id="page_item_5" href="?location=contacto">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a id="page_item_6" href="?location=help">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But nothing works... The location POST changes but the body's class doesn't change. And either the body's content require (doesn't load home/about/etc.php).

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: fyi, `<body class="<?php echo $location ?>">` is open to XSS

Comment: you were missing a semicolon in body class

Comment: The XSS problem was the semicolon? I added it to my code.

Comment: @user3529213 no semi-colon is required in that particular line as its followed by a closing tag `?>`. The [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) problem is your not protecting from a user adding javascript to the `$_GET['location']` var, thus allowing arbitrary code to be injected into the page when you echo $location in the html. You should use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) when displaying user supplied data back to the user.

Comment: OK, I read that section and It's a bible long, could you please be a little more specific about what characteristic of htmlentities() I should use? Or a link to some example? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing stuff via `GET`, not `POST`.

```
if( isset($_GET['location']) ) {
    $location = $_GET['location'];
} else {
    $location = 'home';
}
```

For future reference, you can print the `GET` and `POST` variables to see which contains what:

```
print_r($_GET);
```

And while on the subject, `$_REQUEST` contains them both:

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

To send POST data, you have to send them with a form - irrelevant here. What you see in URLs query strings is `GET` data, not `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your post to get..
i.e.

```
if( isset($_GET['location']) ) {
    $location = $_GET['location'];
} else {
   $location = 'home'; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You use GET not POST + why dont use $location + "php"? :

```
if( isset($_GET['location']) ) {
            $location = $_GET['location'];

} else {
        $location = 'home';
    }
require 'header.php';
require $location . '.php';
require 'footer.php';
```

Comment: BUT the problem is the browser will try to open anything the user inputs manually on the nav bar... so if he mispells he will get a wreck of a page with a 2 big black errors and nothing loading anymore... Any way to avoid that?

Comment: OK I figured it, I used the file_exists(); to check if the file exists before loading the require. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you can check if page exist before bool file_exists ( string $filename )

Comment: -1 for the **huge security risk** directory/path traversal and file inclusion. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability